# JQuery doesn't have sliding effects (show, slideToggle...)

Tags: jquery

I'm new in Jquery, so sorry about the trivial question, but I'm quite stuck. This JQuery code should do some sliding effect (reveal part of HTML code and hide the three dots, with particular effect). Problem is, that it shows the HTML code between `<span class="toggle"></span>` WITHOUT sliding effect (whatever it is show() or slideToggle(), without or with parameters - slow,fast...). However, when I tried it for the first time, it went good, but after some refreshes it stopped animate. I can't find any obvious problem. Why this behaviour (independently on browser) ?

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-button"> ...</a><span class=\"toggle\">blablabla1</span>
<a href="#" class="toggle-button"> ...</a><span class=\"toggle\">blablabla2</span>
```

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.toggle').hide();
$('.toggle-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    $(this).hide();
});
</script>
```

JQuery is appended in the BODY tag after my HTML code. I'm using this JQuery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your developer console?

Comment: If your jQuery library is being called at the bottom of the page after the HTML, where is your JavaScript/jQuery script in relation?

Comment: It appears to be working in jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ePEj9/.

I'm guessing your JavaScript/jQuery script is running, and THEN you load the jQuery library when it really should be reversed.